# Call super from within a block in initialize

Tags: ruby

I need to define initializers with blocks as in the following code:

```ruby
module Base
  def add_init(&block)
    @init = block
    define_method(:initialize) { |*args| self.class.lookup(self, *args) }
  end

  def lookup(obj, *args)
    obj.instance_exec(*args, &@init)
  end
end

class Foo
  extend Base
  add_init { |s| puts "Init Foo with '#{s}'" }
end

class Bar < Foo
  extend Base
  add_init { |s| super(s); puts "Init Bar with '#{s}'" }
end
```

Just `define_method(:initializer) {}` won't do because I later need to add several blocks and a mechanism on the lookup method to choose which to call.

The problem right now is the following:

```ruby
Foo.new('test')
# Init Foo with 'test'

Bar.new('test')
# TypeError: self has wrong type to call super in this context: Bar (expected #<Class:#<Object:0x007f84590de460>>)
```

How can I get `super` to work as expected within those blocks?

Comment: What is the "expected" way?

Comment: @sawa `Bar.new('test')` # Init Foo with 'test' Init Bar with 'test'